# Call shell skript with specific working directory from R

Tags: r, shell

I have an sh script, that can only be run from a specific directory because it looks for the files in that directory and I don't want to change the sh file.

Suppose the file is in `./sub/script.sh` and the R working directory is `./`

What works is

```
wd = getwd()
setwd("./sub")
system2("./script.sh")
setwd(wd)
```

But I find that rather unhandy. How can I do without changing the R working direcotry?

Comment: What about just `system2("cd sub && ./script.sj")` ?

Comment: `system2("cd ./ && ls")` does not seem to work as an example. I think it's because `system2` uses shQuote. `system` works fine.

Comment: You **should** change the shell script because it’s a bad script. `setwd` really has no place in R — don’t use it.

Comment: I'm with @KonradRudolph here.  Either change it, or if you can't, create a new one that wraps.  Or an R function that does.  [Funcamental Law of Software Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering) still holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `system2` uses shQuote we can only use `system()` and as already pointed out by @Dirk you can then use

```
system("cd ./sub && sh script.sh")
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't pretty, but does the job

```
# A function that will call the script
test <- function(){

  # Current working directory
  cur <- getwd(); 

  # On exit, come back
  on.exit(setwd(cur)); 

  # Change directory
  setwd("~"); 

  # Run the command
  system("pwd"); 

  # Return
  NULL
}
```

Then just call the function `test()`.